Pandas performance of fillna vs. boolean masking + writing value
In an example dataframe with NaNs in the third column, let us compare the performance of fillna() with boolean masking + setting the value:
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(100)
nrows = 10000000
nnan = 25000
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.uniform(0,250000,size=(nrows,3)))
ind_row = np.random.randint(0,nrows,nnan)

df.loc[ind_row, 2] = np.nan

df1 = df.copy()
%timeit df1[2] = df1[2].fillna(999)
df1 = df.copy()
%timeit df1[2].fillna(999)
df1 = df.copy()
%timeit df1.loc[df1[2].isna(),2] = 999

I got the following example timings:
35.1 ms ± 369 μs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
36.4 ms ± 331 μs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
6.23 ms ± 65.5 μs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

and
35.9 ms ± 1.11 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
37.3 ms ± 438 μs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
6.41 ms ± 38.2 μs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

Note that these timings do to not seem to depend much on the ratio of NaNs to non-NaN values.
Why does manual boolean masking appear to be faster than fillna()?

Update 1: The below plot shows the timings for different dataframe sizes generated with the code below and can be compared to @mozway's plot. However, for me there is a clear separation, with boolean masking consistently below fillna(inplace=True) below fillna() for N >= 10^5:

Code:
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import timeit

np.random.seed(100)

nrepeats = 5
nruns = 10

def time_fillna(nrows, output):
    nnan = int(nrows/4)
    df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.uniform(0,250000,size=(nrows,3)))
    ind_row = np.random.randint(0,nrows,nnan)

    df.loc[ind_row, 2] = np.nan

    df1 = df.copy()
    output['fillna_assign'].append(np.min(timeit.repeat('df1[2] = df1[2].fillna(999)', globals=locals(), repeat=nrepeats, number=nruns))/nruns)
    df1 = df.copy()
    output['fillna_only'].append(np.min(timeit.repeat('df1[2].fillna(999)', globals=locals(), repeat=nrepeats, number=nruns))/nruns)
    df1 = df.copy()
    output['fillna_inplace'].append(np.min(timeit.repeat('df1[2].fillna(999,inplace=True)', globals=locals(), repeat=nrepeats, number=nruns))/nruns)
    df1 = df.copy()
    output['bool_mask'].append(np.min(timeit.repeat('df1.loc[df1[2].isna(),2] = 999', globals=locals(), repeat=nrepeats, number=nruns))/nruns)

output = {method:[] for method in ['fillna_assign', 'fillna_only', 'fillna_inplace', 'bool_mask']}

nrows_all = np.logspace(3,8,11).astype(int)
for nrows in nrows_all:
    print(f'Timing for nrows = {nrows}')
    time_fillna(nrows, output)

plt.ion()
plt.plot(nrows_all, output['fillna_assign'], label='fillna_assign')
plt.plot(nrows_all, output['fillna_only'], label='fillna_only')
plt.plot(nrows_all, output['fillna_inplace'], label='fillna_inplace')
plt.plot(nrows_all, output['bool_mask'], label='bool_mask')
plt.loglog()
plt.xlabel('Number of rows')
plt.ylabel('Runtime [s]')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
plt.savefig('timing_fillna.png')


Update 2: Making sure that NaNs are present in repeated timing runs (see comments by @mozway), I get a different result: fillna(inplace=True) and boolean masking comparable, fillna() only without assignment as the fastest:

Code:
def time_fillna_revised(nrows, output):
    nnan = int(nrows/4)
    df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.uniform(0,250000,size=(nrows,3)))
    ind_row = np.random.randint(0,nrows,nnan)

    df.loc[ind_row, 2] = np.nan

    df_insert = df.copy()

    t_fillna_assign = []
    t_fillna_inplace = []
    t_fillna_bool = []
    for i in range(nrepeats):
        time_temp_assign = 0
        time_temp_inplace = 0
        time_temp_bool = 0
        for j in range(nruns):
            df1 = df.copy()
            time_temp_assign += timeit.repeat('df_insert[2] = df1[2].fillna(999)', globals=locals(), repeat=1, number=1)[0]
            df1 = df.copy()
            time_temp_inplace += timeit.repeat('df1[2].fillna(999,inplace=True)', globals=locals(), repeat=1, number=1)[0]
            df1 = df.copy()
            time_temp_bool += timeit.repeat('df1.loc[df1[2].isna(),2] = 999', globals=locals(), repeat=1, number=1)[0]
        t_fillna_assign.append(time_temp_assign)
        t_fillna_inplace.append(time_temp_inplace)
        t_fillna_bool.append(time_temp_bool)
    output['fillna_assign'].append(np.min(t_fillna_assign)/nruns)
    output['fillna_inplace'].append(np.min(t_fillna_inplace)/nruns)
    output['bool_mask'].append(np.min(t_fillna_bool)/nruns)
    df1 = df.copy()
    output['fillna_only'].append(np.min(timeit.repeat('df1[2].fillna(999)', globals=locals(), repeat=nrepeats, number=nruns))/nruns)


Update 3: For NaN-ratio 1/4, (see above plot), the results may be more complicated, see next plot:

For NaN-ratio 1/400 (comment by @ken), the timings are:


Running @mozway's code:


My best guess is that it works in-place. Have you tracked the timing on different sized dfs?

Scaling the dataframe by a factor of 10 (i.e. 10^8 rows) roughly scales timings linearly. Boolean masking remains a factor 4-6 faster than fillna(). When the dataframe gets smaller, the factor gets closer to 1.

This is probably not important here, but since timeit runs the code repeatedly and uses the best run, the timing you see is likely the performance AFTER the NaNs are filled (except for the second one).


Note that these timings do to not seem to depend much on the ratio of NaNs to non-NaN values. This is actually due to the above.


@silence_of_the_lambdas also note that if nrepeat > 1 or nrun > 1, then only the first run will actually have NaNs. Thus you're measuring only one valid datapoint. In contrast in my timing I used 10 independent replicates

Example demonstrating that the timing method is incorrect: timeit.repeat('m = df1[2].isna() ; print(m.sum()) ; df1.loc[m,2] = 999', globals=locals(), repeat=2, number=2)

I added the full code to produce my graph, please give it a try

In the new benchmark, you've changed the ratio of NaNs... If you set it to 1/400 as in the first benchmark, I bet bool_mask would still be the fastest.

@ken: inplace and bool_mask seem comparable.

"Why does manual boolean masking appear to be faster than fillna()?"
could it be faster?
Could boolean indexing be faster in these conditions? Potentially yes.
First of all, fillna can do much more than simply filling NaNs with a value, it can ffill/bfill, but also restrict filling to a number of consecutive NaNs.
On top of that, it also outputs a new Series.
All in all, this is potentially much more work than simply identifying the positions of the NaNs and replacing them in place.
but is it really faster?
It seems however that the difference is not always that clear. I tested a comparison for various sizes and 50% probability to get NaNs and got the following:

For a 1/400 probability to get NaNs, this gives:

In this case, boolean indexing is significantly faster than fillna, but fillna with inplace=True is even faster.
I used a random sampling of 1 or NaN, copied to 3 different columns, then ran:
# fillna_only
df['col'].fillna(999)

# fillna_assign
df['col'] = df['col'].fillna(999)

# fillna_inplace
df['col2'].fillna(999, inplace=True)

# boolean_indexing
df.loc[df['col3'].isna(), 'col3'] = 999

The above graphs was computed with 10 replicates. It seems that the features such as the slight drop in timing for fillna_only around 10⁶ are true. This would indicate internal optimizations or size-effects that could occur depending on the size of the input.
Code:
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import perfplot
import seaborn as sns

def init(N):
    df = pd.DataFrame({'col': np.random.choice([1, np.nan], size=N)})

    # or for a custom probability
    # df = pd.DataFrame({'col': np.random.choice([1, np.nan], p=[399/400, 1/400], size=N)})

    df['col2'] = df['col'].copy()
    df['col3'] = df['col'].copy()
    return df

def fillna_only(df):
    return df['col'].fillna(999)

def fillna_inplace(df):
    df['col2'].fillna(999, inplace=True)

def fillna_assign(df):
    df['col'] = df['col'].fillna(999)
    return df

def boolean_indexing(df):
    df.loc[df['col3'].isna(), 'col3'] = 999
    return df

out = []

for _ in range(10):
    out.append(perfplot.bench(
    setup=init,
    kernels=[fillna_only, fillna_assign, fillna_inplace, boolean_indexing],
    n_range=2**np.arange(28),
    equality_check=None,
    max_time=10
))
    
results = (pd.concat([pd.DataFrame(x.timings_s, columns=x.n_range, index=x.labels) for x in out])
             .rename_axis(index='method', columns='len(df)').stack().reset_index(name='timing (s)')
          )

ax = sns.lineplot(df, x='len(df)', y='timing (s)', hue='method')
ax.set_xscale('log')
ax.set_yscale('log')

timeit with replicates
Be aware that in your timing code, only the first replicate seems to have NaNs
df1 = df.copy()
timeit.repeat('m = df1[2].isna() ; print(m.sum()) ; df1.loc[m,2] = 999', globals=locals(), repeat=2, number=2)

2212512  <- lots of NaNs in the first replicate
0        <- now they're gone
0
0

[0.06422067689709365, 0.021104251965880394]

Your code:

Your code with nrepeats = 1 ; nruns = 1:


That doesn't really mean it should take longer if the other args are not defined. It seems like a clear case for a fast path

fillna(inplace=True) does reduce the time from 35 to 13 ms for the sizes given here. This is, in any case, still a factor of 2 above the boolean masking.

@roganjosh I agree, but it's not always so simple. Actually boolean indexing is not always faster. I'll update the answer

@silence_of_the_lambdas check the update, see that it's not so obvious.

@mozway: Yes. There are some interesting results, e.g. I would have assumed that fillna(inplace=True) always outruns default fillna(inplace=False). I assume you always reset the NaNs for each method, correct (don't know from your fillna_only vs. `fillna_assign`` operating on the same column)? How many runs did you use for the mean time?

Yes, each operation is performed once here per DataFrame size and I used different columns to ensure having the NaNs.

Would be important to run all operations multiple times, to reduce statistical noise.

Not necessarily, but here I agree since we see noise. I'm actually running replicates but it takes times ;)

@silence_of_the_lambdas I updated the graph with the average of 10 replicates (an an error band, but it's not really visible since the timings are quite reproducible)

@mozway: I created my own timing plot and added it together with the code to perform the timings to the post. Somehow I do get a clear pattern/trend from N >= 10^5.

@silence_of_the_lambdas It might depend on the hardware. I'll try to replicate on another computer

inplace actually works inplace in this instance? The API is a mess :(

@silence_of_the_lambdas I updated my answer with the output from your code (just swapping the order for consistency of the colors), and it gives a more stable trend, though still different from yours and still with this artifact around 10⁶
